# How to select a random row from an MS Access through VB.NET within a certain set of requirements?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, random

I am trying to get a random row from a certain set of rows within a table from an MS Access database.

The random record must come from the list of records with

`[Difficulty Level] = 1 and [Language Level] = 1.`

In essence, I want to make a query of the records that have Diff.Level 1 and Langu.Level 1, and then from this query, get a random row.

I am using OleDb in SQL from VB.NET.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [learningMaterial]  WHERE  rand() AND [Difficulty Level] = '1' AND [Language Level]= '1'
```

Comment: If the result set is not too huge don't try to do it in SQL. Bring back your rows where difficulty = 1 and language level = 1 then use Linq to `Skip(random number).Take(1)`

Comment: Does your table have a key? In that case your normalise rand() against the key (rand() * Max(yourkey)) and select that one.

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM  [learningMaterial]  WHERE  [Difficulty Level] = '1' AND [Language Level]= '1' ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*ID)*Time())` where ID  must be a numeric unique identifier in your learingMaterial table.

Comment: If this is related to a quiz or exam, selecting a random row in isolation wont assure that it doesnt repeat.  The result could be questions `{7, 3, 1, 3, 2, 7...)`  You might want to clarify the question